# way to copy a string in a structure having character element in c

Tags: c, embedded, memcpy, strcpy

I have structure

```
typedef struct 
{
    char employee_name[32];
    char organisation[32];

}info;
```

How can I Initialized a single or more elements of info .

I am doing like this at the start of the code:

```
info info_data= {
    {'d','a','v','i','d',' ','s','c','h','o','l','e','s','\0'},
    {'x','y','z',' ','I','n','c','\0'}
```

};

This works fine but I want to avoid putting all the names with each character enclosed in ' ' and adding '\0' at the end.Is there a better way to implement this.Code has to run in an `embedded processor and needs to be memory and speed optimized.`

Comment: Regarding to your request for memory and speed optimization: Do you want to change the content of `info` at runtime? If not, you could define `info`as const. This saves RAM but costs flash. And const would need no initialization at runtime.

Comment: I need it to be dynamically assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
info info_data= {
    {"David Scholes"},
    {"xyz Inc"} 
};
```

You can initialise a character array with a string.

If you want to use `strcpy` then proceed as follows:

```
strcpy(info_data.employee_name, "David Scholes");
strcpy(info_data.organisation, "xyz Inc");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
typedef struct 
 {
         char employee_name[32];
         char organisation[32];

 }info;


 info info_data = {{"david scholes"}, {"xyz Inc"}};
```